# ValueError: Cannot assign must be an instance in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I am new to django and I'm trying to insert some data into the database through a form but I am getting an error while inserting the data. How can I solve this issue?

I have these models which are connected together:

models.py

```
class Major(models.Model):
    major_cd = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'major'

class Percentages(models.Model):
    # major_cd = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    major_cd = models.OneToOneField(
        Major,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        primary_key=True,
        db_column='major_cd'
    )
    perc = models.FloatField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'percentages'
```

this is my from:

per.html

```
<form id="addPercentage" action="">     

    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-2">
            <input class="form-control" type="number" name="major_cd" placeholder="Major Code" required min=1000 max=9999>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-2">
            <input class="form-control" type="number" name="perc" placeholder="Percentage" required>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-2" style="padding-right: 2%;">
        <button class="btn btn-info form-control" type="submit">ADD</button>
    </div>
       
</form>
```

script:

```
$("form#addPercentage").submit(function() {
    var majorCodeInput = $('input[name="major_cd"]').val().trim();
    var perc_Input = $('input[name="perc"]').val().trim();
    
    if (majorCodeInput  && perc_Input) {
        // Create Ajax Call
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '{% url "create-percentages" %}',
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            data: {
                'major_cd' : majorCodeInput,
                'perc' : perc_Input,  
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.Perc) {
                  appendToPerTable(data.Perc);  // Funcion to append data
                }
            }
        });
      } else {
        alert("All fields must have a valid value.");
    }
    $('form#addPercentage').trigger("reset");
    return false;
});
```

views.py:

```
class CreatePercentage(View):
    def  post(self, request):
        major_cd = request.POST.get('major_cd', None)
        perc = request.POST.get('perc', None)
       
        obj = Percentages.objects.create(
            major_cd =  major_cd,
            perc = perc,
        )

        Perc = {'major_cd':obj.major_cd,'perc':obj.perc }

        data = {
            'Perc': Perc
        }
        return JsonResponse(data)
```

Error:

---

ValueError: Cannot assign "'9999'": "Percentages.major_cd" must be a "Major" instance.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `major_cd` requires an instance, so you need to use `major_cd_id=major_cd`.

Comment: You should also take a good look at Django's forms, they make what you're doing a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

```
    obj = Percentages.objects.create(
        major_cd =  major_cd,
        perc = perc,
    )
```

When you do that, `major_cd` is the string "9999", it should be a `Major` instance. So you have to do, if you are sure the major_cd instance exists:

```
    obj = Percentages.objects.create(
        major_cd =  Major.objects.get(major_cd=int(major_cd)),
        perc = perc,
    )
```

Comment: I think I understand the issue, the problem is that I'm inserting a new data which is not even present in the Major table. Do I have to insert into the Major model first and then insert to the Percentages model?

Comment: Yes you have to.

Comment: in my case it's unable to fetch value of   major_cd